# Nodes not talking

Tags: erlang, cluster-computing

I am using Ubuntu 9 and I start two nodes with:

`erl -name node1 -setcookie demo`

and

`erl -name node2 -setcookie demo`

yet when I run "nodes()" the nodes do not see each other and it returns an empty list. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because they are not connected unless they communicate with each other, e.g. by one pinging the other:

`(node1@<host>)> net_adm:ping(node2@<host>).`

Note that if you checked the nodes with `net_adm:names()`, they would have been visible via epmd.

Comment: I did that but it returns "pang". Each node if pinging itself gets a "Pong" though

Comment: Is your hostname included in the hosts file?

Comment: Also, try using -sname <name> instead. This will create local nodes which are easier to connect. (-sname creates short host names and -name creates long ones).

Comment: How do I add my hostname to the hosts file?

Comment: I tried with -sname instead of -name when running erl, but still the nodes do not see each other

Comment: There should be a hosts file at /etc/hosts, or \Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts. You must add host to be translated into 127.0.0.1, e.g. `127.0.0.1 localhost myhost`. Alternatively you could use localhost, or 127.0.0.1 as your hostname to check if things are working...